# nodejs + sqlite3; callback to route returns empty array

Tags: node.js, express

I have an sqlite3 database with some seed data in it. I have the following function, which does work when I run it from the terminal:

```
const db = require('./conn');

function select_user (callback) {

    let q = `select uid, uname, pwd from usr`;

    db.all(q, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('select error = ' + err)
            callback(err);
        }
        callback(rows);
    });
}

// select_user((d) => {console.log(d)});

module.exports = { select_user };
```

When I'm calling from a route, however, I get back an empty array. This is the code:

```
var  crud = require('../models/crud');
    
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        crud.select_user((d) => { res.render('index.ejs', { title: JSON.stringify(d)})});
})
```

This will render "this is a [] page" I would like this to render the returned data. I've searched high and low for an answer, seen many examples that apparently work, and I don't see what I could be doing wrong here.

Additional note: if I don't use JSON.stringify(), the result is "undefined."

In case they are relevant, these are the files that are being called:

conn.js:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

const db = new sqlite3.Database('db.sql', (err) => {
    if (err){
        console.log('err' + err);
    }

    console.log('connected to db');
});


module.exports = db;
```

index.ejs:

```
<p>this is a
<% if (title) { %>
<%- title %>
<% } %>
page</p>
```

app.js is the standard Express template. I haven't made any major changes to that file.

Another update:

I blew out the file tree and started over. The database can connect and build the `usr` table and load in data. Now, when I call from the route, I get `Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: usr`.

Comment: How do you handle `title` in `index.ejs`?

Comment: @oneturkmen; it's just an html template. If I have a regular word there, it will render fine. I also attempted to simply console.log() the result, which renders "undefined" unless I use JSON.stringify(), which will render "[]." I removed all of that so it's hopefully easier to understand.

Comment: try loggin the value in console inside the callback before rendering the ejs template. whats the value of d there. `crud.select_user((d) => { console.log(d); res.render('index.ejs', { title: JSON.stringify(d)})})`

Comment: @anees, the value is [], and it is also [] if I log the value before the callback in select_user().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that a new database file was being built in the root directory after I made a call from the route directory. I was expecting the crud file to be called from the models directory.

To block the relative path, I used this solution:

[Dealing with Relative Paths with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766734/dealing-with-relative-paths-with-node-js)

My conn.js file now looks like this:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var path = require('path')

db_path = path.join(__dirname, 'db.db');

const db = new sqlite3.Database(db_path , (err) => {
    if (err){
        console.log('err' + err);
    }

    console.log('connected to db');
});


module.exports = db;
```

Hopefully this helps someone who is running into the same issue.